# Для чего использовать layout_height="0px" вместо "warp_content"?

Tags: android, xml, height

Не раз видел в примерах при указании высоты View элемента, то что указывают высоту равной **0px**. Вот живой пример, для **ViewPager** указана высота в **0px**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Объясните пожалуйста, что это значит. Получается **ViewPager** отображен в макете как горизонтальная невидимая полосочка. Разве просто обернуть по содержимому не подойдет (wrap_content)? С какой целью применяют этот способ?

Comment: у него еще выставлено android:layout_weight="1", что при комбинации с  android:layout_height="0px" означает, что он собой замостит все пространство по вертикали

Comment: так **much_parent** не подойдет для этой цели?

Comment: `0px/dp/dip` используется совместно с атрибутом `weight`. И не путайте слова `match` и `much`

Comment: конкретно в этом примере match_parent ситуацию не изменит. Вообще  layout_weight это атрибут "вес", который отвечает за пропорциональное размещение вьюх на экране. Скажем, надо чтобы в активити один объект занимал 2/3 всего экрана, а второй объект треть. Тогда выставляем layout_weight="0.7" у первого и 0.3 у второго. Примерно так

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`layout_height` (`layout_width`) равный *0px* указывается, насколько я могу припомнить, только в одном случае - когда ширина (высота) расcчитывается с помощью "весов" - атрибута `android:layout_weight`.

Делается это для того, чтобы:

Во первых - не тратилось время на бесполезное вычисление заданной в параметре высоты (а `wrap_content` и `match_parent` довольно ресурсоемкие атрибуты), так как оно потом все равно будет изменено на рассчитанное по весу.

Во вторых - при расчете, значение текущего размера виджета, отличное от нуля, будет влиять на результат расчета "веса" и вы получите не совсем то, что ожидаете.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение) а то все не мог понять зачем так делать если с **wrap_content** и **much_parent** визуальный результат тот же самый.

Comment: А на сколько **wrap_content** и **match_parent** ресурсоемкие? Это актуально только для старых или очень слабых телефонов? Или же это реально ощутимо даже на мощных аппаратах, если программа очень большая и прожерливая?

Comment: вы можете посмотреть исходники (они находятся в свободном доступе), как рассчитывается значение `wrap_content` (`match_parent`). В общем то, конечно, эти расчеты не грузят проц на 100% на полчаса - значения рассчитываются в довольно больших количествах (посмотрите разметки) - как при этом себя чувствует устройство, вы можете оценить по самому устройству. НО! сколько бы времени и ресурсов это не занимало, если есть возможность этого не делать - эти расчеты не нужно делать, независимо от мощности устройства.