# Как сделать, чтоб LinearLayout выделял всем item одинаковое по размеру место?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-linearlayout

Я с помощью `BaseAdapter` устанавливаю в `ListView` XML файл со своей разметкой. В `ListView` в каждой строчке должно быть 3 столбца каждый из которых должен занимать 33% по ширине. Не больше ни меньше!

**Вот я собираю такой XML : **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="100"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvForHebrew"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="33"
    android:text="@string/forHerbrew"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvForTranscription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="33"
    android:text="@string/forTrans"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvForTranslate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="33"
    android:text="@string/fortrans"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Но все равно когда я устанавливаю в первое `TextView` текст, то он растягивается на где то на 70% по горизонтали, а остальные 2 `TextView` разделяют между собой остальных 30%. Я рассчитывал что каждый `item` займет третью часть по горизонтали. 
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: [Пункт 2 этого ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/481860/177345)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="3"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvForHebrew"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/forHerbrew"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvForTranscription"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/forTrans"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvForTranslate"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/fortrans"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Если с помощью весов происходит разделение размера всего контейнера на части, то `weightSum` можно не указывать, он будет вычислен из сумм частей. Используется, когда надо задать определенный вес не всем элементам в контейнере, чтобы разница между суммой частей и параметром `weightSum` осталось под элементы без веса.

Comment: А еще такой вопрос: как между частями сделать отступ, чтоб они занимали одинаковый размер но был небольшой отступ между ними? А то получается, что одна часть и сразу следующая и выходит, что они сливаются визуально...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko используйте ```padding/margin```

Comment: Попробовал и не до конца могу понять, `padding` делает сдвиг как то к середине, а `margin` как будто со всех сторон делает отступ? или как? не могу понять...

Comment: padding - отступ внутри элемента, margin - отступ снаружи. При этом если размеры высчитываются на основе весов, то padding не учитывается при расчете размера элемента, а margin учитывается уменьшая распределяемое по весам пространство.

Answer (score 4):

Установите у всех TextView ширину в 0:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Comment: А еще такой вопрос: как между частями сделать отступ, чтоб они занимали одинаковый размер но был небольшой отступ между ними? А то получается, что одна часть и сразу следующая и выходит, что они сливаются визуально...

Answer (score 4):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvForHebrew"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/forHerbrew"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvForTranscription"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/forTrans"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvForTranslate"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/fortrans"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Вот так попробуйте

Comment: А еще такой вопрос: как между частями сделать отступ, чтоб они занимали одинаковый размер но был небольшой отступ между ними? А то получается, что одна часть и сразу следующая и выходит, что они сливаются визуально...

Comment: поиграйтесь в marginLeft и marginRight у каждых TextView. Должно помочь