# Отображение макета на одном разрешении с разной плотностью

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

Имеется  layout приложения,  запустив  приложение на трех экранах  с одним разрешениям и разными  dpi -  я получил такую картинку. У меня вопрос как сделать так что бы на всех экранах это смотрелось одинаково.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBackgroundGrey"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/header_button_shape_baground">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"


        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    android:text="NEXT"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:paddingBottom="25dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

fragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:background="@color/colorBackgroundGrey"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"

    >

    <TextView style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum"
        android:id="@+id/mainWord"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingTop="102.5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="44sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/translateWord"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainWord"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="29dp"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewExample1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewExample2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation."
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewExample1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что хотите, чтобы, положим, белое поле занимало всегда строго определённый процент высоты экрана?

Comment: Если Вы не много опишете для чего Вам это, то будет проще Вам помочь. Сейчас же ощущение что Вы хотите чего то очень странного и неправильного. Обычно спрашивают наоборот, как сделать что бы при разном разрешении выглядело одинаково.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  да, вы правильно поняли! как это реализовать!?

Comment: @xkor дело в том, что если взять к примеру другое разрешение и так же на разных плотностях, то картинка будет примерно аналогичная. В зависимости он разрешения - дизайн  белее ли менее тянется, а вот при разных плотностях возникает данная проблема

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вы хотите сделать что бы белая область и серая область распределялись по высоте по процентам а не по размеру их содержимого, то замените  RelativeLayout на LinearLayout и задайте атрибут `android:layout_weight` для этих элементов, а высоту выставьте в 0.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundGrey"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainWord"
            style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:paddingTop="102.5dp"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="44sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/translateWord"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mainWord"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="29dp"
            android:text="sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="46dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="46dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewExample1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewExample2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation."
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Получилось:)  а почему android:layout_height  указывается "0dp"  ?

Comment: @KirillStoianov потому что указание каких либо значений(помимо "0dp") для android:layout_height - бессмысленно(пишут даже не желательно), так как у нас указывается android:layout_weight.

Comment: @KirillStoianov [Для чего использовать layout_height=“0px” вместо “warp_content”](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/481860/177345)