# Макет экрана. Элементы в Listview располагаются не правильно

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть макет экрана, на котором расположен Listview.

Создал кастомный адаптер, кастомный item.xml с textView, checkbox и imageButton.

(Скрин сделан с включенной отладкой макетов экрана)

[image: Скрин проблемы]

**Никак не могу добиться, чтобы checkbox и imageButton(3 точки) были прикреплены к правому краю экрана, независимо от того, какой размер названия пункта.**

Мучился с весами для каждого из слоёв и элементов, мучился с layout:gravity, gravity и foreground_gravity, тупо прибавлял пробелы в текст, чтобы размеры текста были одинаковыми, но от изменения размера экрана снова менялось положение элементов справа.

Также пытался менять LinearLayout'ы, их свойства и создавал разные варианты слоёв на экране.

RelativeLayout пробовал, съезжает туда-сюда, так что не решился его использовать

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

                android:text="Название"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:onClick="myClickHandler"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Дерево компонентов одного итема

[image: скрин дерева]

Ну и код макета экрана с Листвью

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
tools:context="ru.diitcenter.molitvi.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю почти то же самое, но покомпактнее и точно работающее.

для айтема:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="some text"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:onClick="myClickHandler"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Для списка:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Если виджет имеет атрибут `android:layout_weight`,то длина стороны, к которой он применяется, [указывается *0dp*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/481860/177345)

Comment: проверил, заработало, спасибо. Единственное - студия жаловалась на `android:layout_height="0dp"`, пока не удалил вес и не поставил высоту врап_контент

Comment: Не очень понятно зачем через TableLayout... Не могли бы пояснить?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Когда-то давно я делал аналогичный айтем, было так, что если сделать то же самое на одном  `LinearLayout`, при длинном тексте разметка "ломалась", но сейчас я не могу воспроизвести, может там отличия какие то были в используемых виджетах. Да, в данном случае `LinearLayout` уместнее .

Answer (score 2):

С разметкой в `item.xml` у Вас все в прядке.

Измените у `ListView` `android:layout_width` на `match_parent`

Comment: Ваш совет тоже помог, спасибо, но он уже был в реализации выше

Answer (score 2):

При указании веса один из параметров (ширина/высота) должны быть нулевыми. При этом, сделайте всего два ребёнка в основном контейнере. Один (три точки) шириной жёстко заданной, а второй на всё оставшееся место.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Название"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:checked="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

И да - задайте списку ширину во весь экран:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"/>
```

Comment: тоже проверил Ваш код. `imageButton ` цепанулся к правой стороне, но чекбокс так и остался рядом с текствью

Comment: Вы не говорили ничего про положение чекбокса. Только про три точки

Comment: Чтоб чекбокс вправо сдвинуть надо текствью вес только проставить и второй линеар не нужен

Comment: да, сработало, спасибо)